# How to catch when service died?

Tags: android, service

Hi i am using service on devises from API 15.
I need to catch when service die itself or when user kill app from task and service stop.

here is my service:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimerIntent = new Intent(SERVICE_TIMER_BROADCAST);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null){
            mTimerType = intent.getExtras().getInt(TIMER_TYPE_KEY);
            mTimer.run();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

@Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("test", "onDestroy");
        setLoginStatusFailed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.d("test", "onTaskRemoved");
        setLoginStatusFailed();
    }

    private void setLoginStatusFailed(){
        new USB_LogOut(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

on KitKat device it works great, but when I tried it on 4.0 it is does't work...

Any ideas why it happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Services can't run 24 hours a day.  At some point the system will very likely need to kill your process to have memory for elsewhere, and you will go away without a call to `onDestroy()`.  Later the system will restart the process and service.

You can return `start_sticky` in `onStartCommand` for restart the service if the service killed by the system or user as well .

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle

You can refer Google forum for more details https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/2DTkEk73xpk

Comment: thanks, I know this :) the question is how to catch when the service died

Comment: As i said in my answer it's not possible to get triggered when service destroy in certain situations..just think , the system may killed some services when the low memory scenario comes to scene ...probably it will kill the service and there you get triggered in on destroy it's possible to restart the service by the programmer at the moment itself..here what step taken by the system to handle the scenario is waste right..i said an example...

Comment: sorry, when I sad "died by itself" I mean momen when the timer finish and will run command stopSelf().
my goals is to catch moment when service died, but i doesnt whant to restart it )
in fact all this work good on devices 4.2, 4.4, 5.0, but not on 4.0

Comment: yep, but when user kill app from task - it still  doesnt work